# can not get the right output in my java tictactoe game

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

Hi Guys I really need help with my assignment. I tried doing it but I can't figure it out.

starting board:

```
1  2  3     

4  5  6     

7  8  9
```

result desire:

```
x  2  3

o  x  6

7  o  x
```

however every time I execute I always get the following whenever there is a winner:

```
x 2 3

o x 6 

7 o 9
```

**Lastly, how do I calculate the winning ratio of the player that won the most?**

Restrictions:

- You must use a 2D array for the tic-tac-toe board. (I am aware I did not used a 2D array because I could not figure out how to make the compiler accept 1-9 input from a 2D array.  )
- You cannot use classes for this question.
- You can use static methods if you like.

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class TicTacToe {    public static String answer = "yes";
  public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static String getName(int noPlayer) {
      System.out.print("Enter name of Player " + noPlayer + ": ");
      return input.next();
  }

  public static int getMove(String board[], String player) {
      printBoard(board);
      System.out.print("Enter move for " + player + ": ");
      int move = input.nextInt() - 1;
      while (moveTaken(board, move)) {
          System.out.println("Move taken.");
          System.out.print("Enter move for " + player + ": ");
          move = input.nextInt() - 1;
      }
      return move;
  }
  public static String gameResult(String board[]) {
      final int checkWin[][] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8},
                                      {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8},
                                      {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};
      for (int[] i: checkWin) {
          if (board[i[0]].equals(board[i[1]]) && board[i[0]].equals(board[i[2]]) && board[i[1]].equals(board[i[2]])) {
              if (board[i[0]].equals("O")) {
                  return "X wins";
              }
              else {
                  return "O wins";
              }
          }
      }
      if (!board[0].equals("1") && !board[1].equals("2") && !board[2].equals("3") &&
          !board[3].equals("4") && !board[4].equals("5") && !board[5].equals("6") &&
          !board[6].equals("7") && !board[7].equals("8") && !board[8].equals("9")) {
          return "draw";
      }
      return "not completed";
  }
  public static boolean moveTaken(String board[], int move) {
      if (board[move].equals("O") || board[move].equals("X")) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  public static void printBoard(String board[]) {
      System.out.println(" " + board[0] + " " + board[1] + " " + board[2] +
                         "\n" +
                         " " + board[3] + " " + board[4] + " " + board[5] +
                         "\n" +
                         " " + board[6] + " " + board[7] + " " + board[8]);
  }
  public static void conclusion(String result, String pO, String pX) {
      if (result.equals("O wins")) {
          System.out.println(pO + " wins!");

      }
      else if (result.equals("X wins")) {
          System.out.println(pX + " wins!");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Draw.");
      }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {

        String X = getName(1);
        String O = getName(2);

    int count = 1;
    do{   

      String nextPlayer = X;
      String board[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
      int move;
          while (gameResult(board).equals("not completed")) {
              move = getMove(board, nextPlayer);
              if (nextPlayer == X) {
                  board[move] = "X";
                  nextPlayer = O;
              }
              else {
                  board[move] = "O";
                  nextPlayer = X;
              }
          }
      System.out.println("game up to date: " + count);

     conclusion(gameResult(board), X, O);

      System.out.println("Do you want to play again? yes or no");
       answer = input.next();
       count++; 


  }
      while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));




    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Seems it is a School or Collage Problem. It is very bad to solve those school problem using stack overflow.

Comment: 2D arrays: `String[][] field = new String[3][3];` & `field[i][j] = String.valueOf((i*field.length)+j+1;`

Comment: thank you! I also manage to make it work in 2darray =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only print the board in `getMove`, prior to performing the move. Therefore the last move is never displayed.

You should add a call to `printBoard` when the game ends.

Here's one possible place to add it :

```
...
System.out.println("game up to date: " + count);
printBoard(board);
conclusion(gameResult(board), X, O);
...
```

Comment: can you please help me add a counter for every win a player get display their ratio once program ended? please

Comment: @anthony Well, your `conclusion` method can return an int that indicates who won (for example 1 - first player won, 0 - draw, -1 second player won). Then the main method can use that value in order to update counters for the number of wins of each player.